# document.evaluate allways returns null in singleNodeValue on some pages\sites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, document.evaluate

page: http://h4z.it/View/-20100729_designtea.jpg

code to execute in console:
`document.evaluate("//img",document,null,9,null).singleNodeValue`

or

`document.evaluate("//a",document,null,9,null).singleNodeValue`

or even

`document.evaluate("//html",document,null,9,null).singleNodeValue`

result (tested both with Chrome and Firefox): `null`

I thought that page overrided document.evaluate but it shows

> document.evaluate
>
> function evaluate() { [native code] }

and `delete document.evaluate` does not help, so what else can it be which breaks `document.evaluate` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you show in your question uses an xhtml namespace and probably so do the other pages that you are seeing this happen on.

Since you are setting `null` for the namespace resolver argument it cannot find the elements.

[MDN Using XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Implementing_a_Default_Namespace_Resolver)

> Note: XPath defines QNames without a prefix to match only elements in
>   the null namespace. There is no way in XPath to pick up the default
>   namespace as applied to a regular element reference (e.g.,
>   p[@id='_myid'] for xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'). To match
>   default elements in a non-null namespace, you either have to refer to
>   a particular element using a form such as
>   ['namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' and name()='p' and
>   @id='_myid'] (this approach works well for dynamic XPath's where the
>   namespaces might not be known) or use prefixed name tests, and create
>   a namespace resolver mapping the prefix to the namespace.

So if you setup a resolver than you can access the element correctly by prefixing them:

```
function resolver(prefix){
   return prefix === "xhtml" ? 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' : null;
}

document.evaluate("//xhtml:a",document,resolver,9,null).singleNodeValue
```

[.evaluate doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate)

[Creating Resolver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Implementing_a_User_Defined_Namespace_Resolver)

If you want to get a node without having to know the namespace you can use `local-name()` XPath function as part of the expression

```
document.evaluate("//*[local-name()='img']",document,null,9,null).singleNodeValue
```

Comment: Can that be done without declaring resolver function? like `document.evaluate("//xhtml",document,"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",9,null).singleNodeValue`

Comment: evaluate expects the resolver argument to be a function, so you could just use an anonymous function, `function(){ return 'blahblahblah';}` as the argument, also edited answer to show how to make an expressions without knowing the namespace