# Javascript retrieve absolute XPATH via ID of Node

Tags: javascript, xpath

Hello am trying to retrieve the XPATH of a document via the ID of the node, I saw this to be a simple matter when looking at the code a simple:

//iframe[@id=key];

But it won't work, I've tried every combination of syntax I can think of and not luck, the print out is "undefined". This is my code

```
function getNode(htmlURL, filename, xpath, callback){
                var key = filename+xpath;

                var frame =  document.getElementById(key);         

                frame.addEventListener("load", function(evt){
                var value= frame.contentDocument.evaluate(xpath, frame.contentDocument, null,9,null);
                if(value!=null){

                callback(value);

                }           
                }, false);

                frame.contentWindow.location.href = htmlURL;

                }

                function init(htmlURL, filename, xpath){

                getNode(htmlURL, filename, xpath, function(node) { console.debug(node.outerHTML); });

                }
```

Am trying to get the xpath inside the iframe, so I thought I'd have to point it to the xpath to the iframe first

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find an element inside of an iframe then you need to use the evaluate method on the document in the iframe e.g.

```
frame.contentDocument.evaluate(xpath, frame.contentDocument, null,9,null)
```

But if you set the src to load an HTML document don't expect to be able to access nodes in the document in your code setting the src, instead set up an onload event handler to wait until the document has been loaded. In the event handler you can then access the nodes in the loaded document.

Comment: I have a simple onload now that goes to another function that simply says alert("hello world");,but the alert never appears :(

Comment: How do you set up the onload handler exactly?

Comment: I just used the iframes onload attribute and pointed it to retrieveHTML()

Comment: I have put together an example at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/2014/test2014030601.html which works for me with current versions of Firefox, Chrome and Opera, it outputs the `outerHTML` of the `p` element in the iframe to the console of the web browser.

Comment: Note that that example makes no effort to remove event listeners, you would need to do that in a real application to avoid getting lots of events handled in case the function is called several times. But it should show how to load a document and then onload find an element using XPath. And of course all cross frame scripting is subject to the same origin policy so don't expect to be able to load a document from a different origin and then be able to script it from the outer document.

Comment: Well thats exactly what am trying to do :'(. I thought iFrames allowed people to get around that

Comment: An iframe allows you to load a document from a different origin but then you are not allowed to script it, unless the server cooperates, see CORS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.

Comment: Cheers, all this content will end up in an iframe anyway and hopefully on the same origin, am going to quickly test it now

Comment: If you check the original post this is the code am using now, I still get an undefined, could be due to https port changes that its breaking

Comment: No, an event listener, the second argument to `addEventListener`, has to be a function reference, like in my sample an anonymous function. Your code calls `retrieveHTML(xpath, key)`, that is not going to work.

Comment: That may explain is because the cross origin policy should not longer be an issue, since you can reach the linked file via a relative path, meaning it has to be in the same origin, I'll take another look at your example

Comment: Above is what I finally have, still no luck

Comment: You set `var value= frame.contentDocument.evaluate` but then have `if(node!=null)`.

Comment: Right I've gotta set a few things up, the machine and builds need a bit of work, cheers for all your help :)

Comment: Well its official javascript hates me, it just really doesn't want to give me the HTML scrap

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` because your xpath syntax translates to a code comment in JavaScript.

What you probably want is:

```
        var finalxpath = "//iframe[@id=key]";
```

Note the quote characters which makes your xpath a string literal value.

Comment: But now all thats printed out is //iframe[@id=key]

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with the xpath value? Your code sample only depicts how you compute it's value. You may want to open another question here with the updated code (now that undefined is resolved) and add the code where you're trying to evaluate the xpath against some sort of document.

Comment: Ill give you the full code to make it easier, check first post

Comment: Ok, so you're using `document.evaluate` - have a look at this discussion and see if it applies to your HTML page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146056/document-evaluate-allways-returns-null-in-singlenodevalue-on-some-pages-sites